# R create data frame by extracting row names and max col name

Tags: r

I have a matrix/dataframe `M` of the following form

```
   A        B        C  D      E
2       0 0.132041187 0.100847971 0.000000 0.76711084
4       0 0.132041187 0.100847971 0.000000 0.76711084
5       0 0.001506186 0.005164067 0.982894 0.01043572
7       0 0.132041187 0.100847971 0.000000 0.76711084
11      0 0.001506186 0.005164067 0.982894 0.01043572
14      0 0.132041187 0.100847971 0.000000 0.76711084
```

I need to extract the row name and the column name with the max value to a new data frame.

I tried `max.col()`, but, this is what i get:

```
head( colnames(M)[max.col(M, ties.method="first"), drop=FALSE])
[1] "E"   "E"   "D" "E"   "D" "E"
```

the result doesn't store the row name. How to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `max.col` gives only the column index for each row.  Use that index to get the corresponding column names. For the `rownames` we can just use `rownames(M)` and create a new `data.frame` with these info. To get the 'value', we `cbind` the row index with the column index and extract the corresponding elements in 'M' based on that.

```
i1 <- max.col(M, ties.method="first")
data.frame(rn=rownames(M), cn= colnames(M)[i1], 
                value= M[cbind(seq_len(nrow(M)), i1)])
#  rn cn     value
#1  2  E 0.7671108
#2  4  E 0.7671108
#3  5  D 0.9828940
#4  7  E 0.7671108
#5 11  D 0.9828940
#6 14  E 0.7671108
```